# How to separate integers using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am a noob at programming so I might have trouble with some key terms.
I'm trying to write a program where a user types in a minimum number and a maximum number and it generates a random number. After that I want to know how many even numbers and odd numbers are in the random generated number. I was able to successfully complete the first part but I am having trouble detecting how many even and odd numbers are in the random generated number.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**
 Ex:
        Random generated number is: 478,099
        # of even digits:     2
        # of odd digits:      3

I tried creating local variables that did not work, I want to use a switch case statement but I am having trouble. For now I used a for loop but I want to use a switch case.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###"); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = -1;
    int min = 0;
    int [] diffvalue = new int [1];
    System.out.println("Enter in a maximum value: ");
    max = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter in a minimum value: ");
    min = scanner.nextInt();
    if (min > max)
    {
    System.out.println("Your minimum value is greater then your 
          maximum value.");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
        diffvalue[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    }
    System.out.println("Random Value: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(fmt.format(diffvalue[i]));
     }
}
  int l = diffvalue[i];
   while (l > 0)
  {
  switch ((l % 10) % 2) 
    {
    case 1:
        odd++;
        break;
    default:
        even++;
 } 
  l /= 10;
        }

    }
```

I can't look at the whole number separately.

```
 **EDIT 1**
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    public class MyClass 
    {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###"); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = -1;
    int min = 0;
    int [] diffvalue = new int [1];
    System.out.println("Enter in a maximum value: ");
    max = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter in a minimum value: ");
    min = scanner.nextInt();
      int even = 0; int odd = 0;
    if (min > max)
    {
        System.out.println("Your minimum value is greater then your 
       maximum value.");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
        diffvalue[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    }
    System.out.println("Random Value: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.println(fmt.format(diffvalue[i]));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
   {
    int l = diffvalue[i];
    while (l > 0)
    {
        switch ((l % 10) % 2) 
        {
            case 1:
                odd++;
                break;
            default:
                even++;
        } 
       l /= 10;
   }
   System.out.println("Even:" + even);
   System.out.println("Odd: " + odd);

}
}
}
```

I have gotten it to detect the even numbers and the odd numbers now I am curious to know if there is a way to do it without having the the two variables (odd, even).

Comment: By, the way this is my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: Should I put the if in the switch case statement?

Answer (score 1):

You are not dividing the value `l` by 10. Which is why it is going into a infinite loop.

```
public static void even(int[] diffvalue)
{
    int even = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
        int l = diffvalue[i];
        while (l > 0)
        {
            if((l % 10)%2==0) // this line is changed
            {
                even++;
            }
            l = l/10; // this line is changed
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you are checking for even, you have to do `...%2 == 0`. Find your errors fixed in the code above.

EDIT: you can also calculate the odd numbers in the same loop, like this:

```
if((l % 10)%2==0) // this line is changed
{
    even++;
}
else 
{
    odd++;
}
```

EDIT3: The code was supposed to go inside the method, not replace the method. 
I do not see any use case for a switch case here, but it can be accommodated like this:

```
public static void even(int[] diffvalue)
{
    int even = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < diffvalue.length; i++)
    {
        int l = diffvalue[i];
        while (l > 0)
        {
            switch ((l % 10) % 2) 
            {
                case 1:
                    odd++;
                    break;
                default:
                    even++;
            } 
        l /= 10;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use a switch case statement. For now I have used a while and a for loop. I don't know how to put the variable in it and separate it. Sorry, for being unclear. Should I put the if statement in the case of the switch?

Comment: If I put the if statement in the switch case it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, how would I save the number of odds and evens like this Ex:  Sample Output:
  Random generated number is: 478,099
  # of even digits:   2
  # of odd digits:   3

Comment: Why are you putting the if statement in the switch statement?

Comment: How else would I use a switch case and make it count? Sorry for being unexperienced.

Comment: Please edit the question with your updated code, I will take a look.

Comment: I have updated it, now I am trying to make it print it but when I put System.out.println(l); it does not work

Comment: Thank you, how would I make it print it.

Comment: using `System.out.println(...)`

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have gotten it to work and print it successfully. Can you please help me find a way to do it without having more then 2 variables (even, odd)?

Comment: What other extra variable is there?

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without having the variables even, odd? Maybe a local variable.